# How can I get the position of the current focused window?

Tags: python, window

I want to take a screenshot of the current focused window on an Ubuntu system with Python, how can I get the position (**left, upper, right, lower**) of the current focused window using the command line ?

**Output of `ps aux | grep -wE 'Xorg|Wayland'`**

```
test        1144  6.9  1.9 798024 76092 tty2     Sl+  13:29  24:20 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
test       29912  0.0  0.0  17668   668 pts/1    S+   19:20   0:00 grep --color=auto -wE Xorg|Wayland
```

Comment: What desktop renderer are you using? Is it Xorg or Wayland? (if you don't know, please [edit] your question and tell us which version and which flavor of Ubuntu you are using, that should help; also show us the output of `ps aux | grep -wE 'Xorg|Wayland'`)

Comment: @terdon Updated my question, I'm not running Wayland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

```bsh
$ xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry --shell
WINDOW=94371847
X=604
Y=229
WIDTH=1303
HEIGHT=774
SCREEN=0
```

If you have the coordinates of the top left corner and the size of the window, it is simple to infer the coordinates you asked for:

- The top right corner will be at X=1907 (604+1303), Y=229
- The bottom left corner will be at X=604, Y=1003 (229+774)
- The bottom right corner will be at X=1907 (604+1303), Y=1003 (229+774)

You could therefore combine this into a little function that gives you the 4 coordinates:

```
showCoords(){
    eval "$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry --shell)"
    topLeft="$X,$Y"
    topRight="$((X+WIDTH)),$Y"
    bottomLeft="$X,$((Y+HEIGHT))"
    bottomRight="$((X+WIDTH)),$((Y+HEIGHT))"
    printf 'top left:%s\ntop right:%s\nbottom left:%s\nbottom right:%s\n' "$topLeft" "$topRight" "$bottomLeft" "$bottomRight"
}
```

If you now run `showCoords`, you will get:

```
$ showCoords
top left:604,229
top right:1907,229
bottom left:604,1003
bottom right:1907,1003
```

Comment: I didn't get from it what I want. (left, upper, right, lower)

Comment: @nakE X and Y give you the position of the left corner, you should be able to get the rest given the width and height, right?

Comment: @terdon I'm not good at math. How can I get what I want from X, Y ?

Comment: @nakE see updated answer. Fra-san, please feel very free to roll that back, I just felt it made more sense to edit your answer than to write my own repeating your approach. Also, note that this doesn't quite work on my Cinnamon. The coordinates are a bit off. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, it seems like an issue with the xdotool output, but my apologies if the fault is mine.